# Binding item in listview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having string values which i got dynamically in an array in a fragment. Now i want to dynamically bind those values in an listview. Below is the code about which i told. How can i do it?

```
NodeList name;
Element line;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

TextView textView;

String i[]=subject_id.split(",");

int a=i.length;

                arrayList.clear();

                for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
                {
                    FetchData fetchData=new FetchData(SERVICE_SUBJECT);
                    fetchData.call(ACTION3,METHOD_FETCH_SUBJECT,OBJECT_NAME_SUBJECT,"bus:Id",i[j]);

                    response = fetchData.getResult();

                    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputSource is = new InputSource();
                    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));

                    Document doc = db.parse(is);
                    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:BLSubject");

                    count = String.valueOf(nodes.getLength());

                    for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(k);

                        name = element.getElementsByTagName("a:Subject");
                        line = (Element) name.item(0);
                        subject_name = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                        System.out.println("Subject:" + subject_name);
                        map.put("Subject", subject_name);

                        name = element.getElementsByTagName("a:Id");
                        line = (Element) name.item(0);
                        subjectid = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                        System.out.println("Id:" + subjectid);
                        map.put("Id", subjectid);

                        arrayList.add(map);
                    }

                }
```

Here, 'i' is the array name which contains subject number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ArrayAdapter`.

There is article with some informations :
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Firstly create adapter like so :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

where `this` is your current `Activity`, second argument is layout with targeted `listview` and`items` is list with your data.

Mapping `listview` to `itemsAdapter` :

```
myListView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

After any change on `items`, call `itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method. This makes listview to update from modified collection.